# Carbon Relay not working correctly

Tags: graphite, statsd, graphite-carbon

i've setup 2 real Servers.

One Statsite (alternative to StatsD) is in front of one "Graphite Stack" (Carbon and Graphite Webapp).

Metrics are collected from Statsite correctly, via UDP. And i just forward them every 10 seconds to carbon cache (TCP Port 2013 of carbon relay).

On my Carbon Server, 3 carbon cache instances (a, b and c) are running behind one carbon relay (consistent-hashing).

I got 3 cache:[a, b, c] sections, all are listening on different ports. The relay section, got those 3 cache instances inside the destinations configkey. I've started each carbon cache via python script, with the option --instance=[a, b, c] and i've started the carbon-relay also with the own python script. I can even see inside the relay log, that all 3 instances are connected.

But inside my Graphite Webapp, i just can see under `carbon.agents.XXXXX-[a, b, c].metricsCount` that all 3 instances got the same count rate each other.

I miss the metrics folder for carbon relay `carbon.relay.XXXX.metricsCount`.

**Am i doing everything right???**

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If so how. obvs if you remember ;)

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are missing a CARBON_METRIC_INTERVAL in the [relay] section of your carbon.conf .